# Create visual webpart for SharePoint Online

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2012

I want to create a visual webpart for SharePoint 2013 Online but I find that the requirement is to install the SharePoint on the local machine.

Another thing, do SharePoint 2013 Foundation support webparts created using Visual Studio?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a Visual Web Part for SharePoint 2013 Online.

Your web part will be contained in a Sandbox Solution which you will develop locally. Once development is complete you will upload the Solution Package created by Visual Studio to SharePoint Online. Once this is done your web part will be available for use.

As mentioned, development will be done locally so you will need a machine that has both SharePoint 2013 (Foundation or Server) and Visual Studio 2012 or 2013.

Here are the steps build and deploy the web part:

- Create a new project based on the "SharePoint 2013 - Empty Project" template
- In the SharePoint Customization Wizard enter the URL of the local SharePoint site you will use for testing during development and choose to "Deploy as a sandboxed solution" (you cannot deploy farm solutions to SharePoint Online)
- Add a new Visual Web Part to the project
- Develop and test the web part locally until it has the desired functionality
- Publish your solution to the SharePoint Online site using the remote publishing feature of Visual Studio (see [How to: Deploy, Publish, and Upgrade SharePoint Solutions on a Remote Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh370987%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))
- Go to you SharePoint Online site and test your web part

One important note: sandbox solutions that contain managed (i.e. VB or C#) code are considered to be deprecated and they may not be supported in future versions of SharePoint. Looking forward, the replacement for web parts contained in sandbox solutions would be App parts that are implemented using the new Cloud App Model.

Answer (score 2):

Napa is good for creating SharePoint Hosted apps only (Client Side code dominant). If you want to communicate with server components, you can remotely develop apps (Provider hosted or Autohosted) using Visual Studio. For the later option, Apps should be enabled on your SharePoint site.

> I cannot find anyway where i can create visual studio webparts for sharepoint 2013 online

Webpart development is not available in SharePoint online. You need to create an App with same functionality.

Comment: You can create web parts in sandbox solutions and deploy them to SharePoint Online

Comment: SharePoint Online does not support autohosted apps anymore. The only way to have a custom app with server components is by developing a provider hosted app.

Answer (score 0):

We can use on-line development environment to create SharePoint Apps. I am not sure if Visual Webpart is supported in SharePoint on-line? May be someone could help us better

[www.napacloudapp.com](https://www.napacloudapp.com/Projects/SharePoint)

[image]

You can set up Visual Studio 2012 for [SharePoint 2013 development offline](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timquin/archive/2013/01/22/setting-up-visual-studio-2012-for-sharepoint-2013-development-offline.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

We can create visual webpart as sandbox solutions using visual studio, but your local machine must have sharepoint also with visual studio. To publish the created sandbox web part you need to right click on solution --> publish --> provide url of site collection where you wanted to add --> provide credentials( if needed).

Now, in gallery section you would get your webpart package. Here you have to activate it.

And it;s Done!

Answer (score 0):

Since only Sandbox solutions are allowed to be deployed in SharePoint Online Site and Visual Web Parts are not supported with in Sandbox Solutions.

So you cannot create Visual Web Part with SharePoint Online.

Better is to create a Standard Web Part locally and upload it to SPO Site.

Comment: Or rather best approach is to replace your WebPart to App driven by REST API based solutions instead of Server Side Code (C#, VB), since such Web Parts are now deprecated and might not be supported in upcoming versions of SharePoint.

Answer (score -3):

I ended up creating installing a visual studio 2013 and sharepoint 2013 foundation on my machine.

I cannot find anyway where i can create visual studio webparts for sharepoint 2013 online

Comment: i know this is all of 5 months too late, but you could create an Azure Developer Environment.  That way you can develop WebParts in an actual implementation without purchasing all the HW, SW, and Licensing to just create the WebParts.