# InitializeControl does not exist in the current context Office365 (Sandbox solution)

Tags: web-part, office-365, visual-studio, sandbox-solution

I am attempting to deploy a **Visual Web Part** (Sandbox Solution) and I am receiving following error:

> The name 'InitializeControl' does not exist in the current context".

I was able to deploy a test Visual Web Part with minimal code, however, this solution is not able to build.

I found that the solutions builds before the following:

1. Add `<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Localizable="False" %>`
2. Add any `<SharePoint:ScriptLink>` or `<SharePoint:CssLink>` attributes in the user control.

Once they are added, the error displays.

In order to deploy, I used the following approach:

[Publish solution to the SharePoint Online site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80164/create-visual-webpart-for-sharepoint-online)

This is after adding the web part to the project, and attempting to build. I've Google'd the error message, and the results are limited.

Please help with any suggestions