# How to deploy Visual Studio project to SharePoint online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, application-pages, deploy

I think this is a simple question: How do I deploy projects from Visual Studio to my SharePoint Online site?

I have searched the internet far and wide for a solution and cannot seem to find anything on this. Obviously I am not on a SharePoint server so when i try to create a new SharePoint empty project, I get an error saying it can't find the hive. This makes total sense since. Is there something I missed? Maybe connecting VS to O365?

Additional info (in case you are curious)... I am trying to create an empty project which will then be turned into a Site Page page. I can do this in SP designer no problem but i need to access the code behind (C#).

Comment: are you talking about the full trust code(solutions) or Add-Ons?

Comment: I am talking about solutions

Comment: You cant deploy the Solution in SharePoint Online.

Comment: Interesting. Then how are developers supposed to get custom Web Parts and such to their SharePoint online sites?

Comment: Here are your options for developing sharepoint  applications https://dev.office.com/sharepoint

Answer (score 2):

Add-ins are future, You have to work on that.
To setup [Set up a development environment for SharePoint Add-ins on Office 365](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179924.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
[SharePoint Online Development for Office 365](https://mva.microsoft.com/liveevents/sharepoint-online-development-for-office-365)

Other hand you can create a sandbox solution locally and test, once done then upload to sharepoint online.[Create visual webpart for SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80164/create-visual-webpart-for-sharepoint-online)

> Most technical people working with Office 365 have known that sandbox
>   coMost technical people working with Office 365 have known that
>   sandbox code has been deprecated for some time. This doesn’t mean any
>   sandbox solution is deprecated however – instead, the deprecation
>   specifically refers to *code* in sandbox solutions, and by that we
>   mean code which uses the server-side API. No

[Source](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2016/08/sandbox-code-disabled-in-Office-365.html)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to access the code behind however you can create a SharePoint add-in with Visual Studio and publish that to your SharePoint online site. REST / JSOM can be used in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

In this link it will how to deploy solutions in sharepoint online http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2012/01/10/how-to-use-visual-studio-11-to-publish-solutions-to-sharepoint-online.aspx

[Office 365 How to: Build and Deploy a Web Part with SharePoint Online](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2011/04/01/office-365-how-to-build-and-deploy-a-web-part-with-sharepoint-online.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

Lot's of wrong things with this question...I don't get why you want to DO SO if you don't have a SP server because THEN it means you CANNOT SO. Same goes for O365 if you don't have a subscription then I am guessing you shouldn't be developing for it? But I could be wrong.

So that said I think the questions here are two:

1. How do I deploy projects from Visual Studio to my SharePoint Online site? - Here's the holy grail for Solutions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330921.aspx It covers local dev and deployment too.
2. If it's anything else then these are developed differently from ground up see google and here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d.aspx