# Deploy code from Visual Studio to Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, visual-studio

does anyone know any good reference on how to deploy code from Visual Studio 2015/2017 to Sharepoint Online? I haven't found any helpful information about it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Means do you want steps to deploy the java script files, css styles and webpart pages ?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online You can create Add-ins.

[To setup Set up a development environment for SharePoint Add-ins on Office 365 SharePoint Online Development for Office 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/set-up-a-development-environment-for-sharepoint-add-ins-on-office-365)

In SharePoint Online Farm trust solution is not allowed so only sandboxed solution can be developed and deployed.

You can create a sandbox solution locally and test, once done then upload to SharePoint online.[Creation of Visual Web Part- Solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80164/create-visual-webpart-for-sharepoint-online).

Sandbox code has been deprecated for some time.  So Suggest you to go for Add-ins.

Waqas also mentioned this in his answers [How to deploy Visual Studio project to SharePoint online site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/202274/how-to-deploy-visual-studio-project-to-sharepoint-online-site)

Comment: So it is not possible to create a custom workflow in VS and to deploy to a lets say document library that already exists n SharePoint?